# Is it true we cannot change the minds of the Gods?

Tags: scripture, gods, philosophy, prayer, sacrifice

Is it true that we cannot change the minds of the Gods, and that we cannot change their plans?

I assume it is true that we cannot change them, but I'm asking to see if there are any scriptures or scholars stating this, or stating otherwise.

It is not sufficient to show an account where a God changed his mind, since it could be talking about how the God *apparently* changed his mind, from the point of view of the human, but didn't actually change his mind, in reality.